# Insert revision information in a header file in VisualSVN

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svn-hooks

I would like to run some sort of post commit hook script on a VisualSVN server in order to either add a file (or simply edit a file) to the repository which will include the revision number (and other revision information). I know this is possible to achieve using client scripts, but I want to do it on the server.
Any thoughts? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 4):

You can manage server hooks via the VisualSVN Server Manager:

1. Start the Server Manager,
2. Select the repository,
3. **Action | All Tasks | Manage Hooks.**

In the dialog it tells you that the revision number is the 2'nd argument. With the revision number, you can use `svn.exe` and `svnlook.exe` to do a lot of other tasks... any use?

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I don't see the manage hooks task. I'll need to upgrade to the latest version I guess. I'll upgrade and check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can use a post-commit hook script to perform the task. However you should understand that you must NOT modify the original transaction itself (i.e. don't try a **start-** or **pre-** commit hooks. Commit of the complementary file with revision details must be performed as a separate one.

In order to retrieve additional revision data you can [use `svnlook.exe` in your hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnlook).

See the [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks):

> While hook scripts can do almost anything, there is one dimension in
>   which hook script authors should show restraint: **do not modify a
>   commit transaction using hook scripts**. While it might be tempting to
>   use hook scripts to automatically correct errors, shortcomings, or
>   policy violations present in the files being committed, doing so can
>   cause problems. Subversion keeps client-side caches of certain bits of
>   repository data, and if you change a commit transaction in this way,
>   those caches become indetectably stale. This inconsistency can lead to
>   surprising and unexpected behavior. Instead of modifying the
>   transaction, you should simply validate the transaction in the
>   pre-commit hook and reject the commit if it does not meet the desired
>   requirements. As a bonus, your users will learn the value of careful,
>   compliance-minded work habits.